# SAML 2.0 - Authenticating a user from a custom Attribute instead of NameId

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

We have a multi-clients (internally identified as "corporates"), web-based software, in which we have implemented SSO via SAML 2.0. Each client is a Corporate, and each Corporate has its own users.

At the moment, the users are identified by the **NameId** property of the SAML response (matching the Username field in our application), and the value of the **Issuer** field allows us to know which Corporate the user is from.

Now, one of our big client has white-labelled the solution, **and is using it in-house, with a single Identity Provider for all of its own clients.** This mean there is a unique **Issuer** value for all SAML messages, and we can no longer rely on that to identify the user's Corporate. Fortunately, their SAML message gives all the information we need, formatted this way:

- The **NameId** value is formatted as *"corporate:username"*
- There is a specific **"companyId"** Attribute, with value *"corporate"*
- There is a specific **"operatorId"** Attribute, with value *"username"*

I guess that identifying the Corporate is then straightforward : we need to check the value of the custom "companyId Attribute and compare that with the Corporate name. Easy.

But what about the username? Is it safe, or does it follow best practices, to check the "**operatorId**" Attribute instead of the **NameID** property ? Or should we in all cases always rely on **NameId**, and therefore put a custom parsing logic in place to extract the corporate and username from the **NameId** ?

How would you do that? I'm not able to find a similar case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to follow your company best practices :), but as soon you have validated the request is all up you and what you agree with your customer. It will be thought harder to maintain because it is an exception.